# jQuery get value after div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="woocommerce-variation-price">
    <span class="price">
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
            <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>
            412.40
            </span> 
        ex. BTW
    </span>
</div>
```

I want to get the text `412.40` and the selector has to include `.woocommerce-variation-price`

Here is the javascript I am currently testing with but with no result (empty alert).

```
<script>
$('select').on('change', function() {
    var variation_price = $('.woocommerce-variation-price').find('.woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol').parent().text();
    alert (variation_price);
});
</script>
```

Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: remove parent() method from your tag and try

Comment: @Jerrinstephen Why? OP want's the number not the currency symbol.

Comment: @Jerrin, then it would only return `€`